# Redux store design – two arrays or one

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I guess this could be applied to any Redux-backed system, but imagine we are building simple React Native app that supports two actions:

1. fetching a list of messages from a remote API
2. the ability to mark those messages as having been read

At the moment I have a `messagesReducer` that defines its state as...

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  messages: [],
  read: []
};
```

The `messages` array stores the objects from the remote API, for example...

```
messages: [
  { messageId: 1234, title: 'Hello', body: 'Example' },
  { messageId: 5678, title: 'Goodbye', body: 'Example' }
];
```

The `read` array stores the numerical IDs of the messages that have been read plus some other meta data, for example...

```
read: [
  { messageId: 1234, meta: 'Something' },
  { messageId: 5678, meta: 'Time etc' }
];
```

In the React component that displays a message in a list, I run this test to see if the message should be shown as being read...

```
const isRead = this.props.read.filter(m => m.messageId == this.props.currentMessage.messageId).length > 0;
```

This is working great at the moment. Obviously I could have put a boolean `isRead` property on the message object but the main advantage of the above arrangement is that **the entire contents of the `messages` array can be overwritten by what comes from the remote API**.

My concern is about how well this will scale, and how expensive the `array.filter` method is when the array gets large. Also keep in mind that the app displays a **list** of messages that could be hundreds of messages, so the filtering is happening for each message in the list. It works on my modern iPhone, but it might not work so well on less powerful phones.

I'm also thinking I might be missing some well established best practice pattern for this sort of thing.

Let's call the current approach **Option 1**. I can think of two other approaches...

**Option 2** is to put `isRead` and `readMeta` properties on the message object. This would make rendering the message list super quick. However when we get the list of messages from the remote API, instead of just overwriting the current array we would need to step through the JSON returned by the API and carefully update and delete the messages in the local store.

**Option 3** is keep the current `read` array but also to add `isRead` and `readMeta` properties on the message object. When we get the list of messages from the remote API we can overwrite the entire `messages` array, and then loop through the `read` array and copy the data into the corresponding message objects. This would also need to happen whenever the user reads a message – data would be duplicated in two places. This makes me feel uncomfortable, but maybe it's ok.

I've struggled to find many other examples of this type of store, but it could be that I'm just Googling the wrong thing. I'm quite new to Redux and some of my terminology is probably incorrect.

I'd really value any thoughts on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) you can memorize the results of the `array.filter` to prevent the array from being filtered when neither the `messages` or `read` arrays have changed, which will allow you to use **Option 1**.

In this way, you can easily store the raw data in your reducers, and also access the computed data efficiently for display. A benefit from this is that you are decoupling the requirements for data structure and storage from the requirements for the way the data is displayed.

You can learn more about efficiently computing derived data in the [redux docs](https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html)

Answer (score 1):

How about using a lookup table object, where the id's are the keys.
This way you don't need to filter nor loop to see if a certain message id is there. just check if the object holds a key with the corresponding id:

So in your case it will be:

```
const isRead = !!this.props.read[this.props.currentMessage.messageId];
```

Small running example:

```js
const read = {
  1234: {
    meta: 'Something'
  },
  5678: {
    meta: 'Time etc'
  }
};

const someMessage = {id: 5678};
const someOtherMessage = {id: 999};

const isRead = id => !!read[id];

console.log('someMessage is ',isRead(someMessage.id));
console.log('someOtherMessage is ',isRead(someOtherMessage.id));
```

**Edit**
I recommend reading about [Normalizing State Shape](https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html) from the `redux` documentations.
There are great examples of designing and organizing the data and state.

Comment: This is an interesting idea. In this case would you just store the **read** data in that format with the message ID as the key, or would you you store it twice – once in this format and once in the way I mentioned in my question?

I guess the main disadvantage of this over @Rob Walker's approach is that the array still has to be "filtered", although doing it using a key is much more efficient.

Comment: i wouldn't store any more data then the `id` (and the meta data that you need). try to keep it simple, a `read` object should hold `read` related data only. and you don't need to filter here as this is an object and not an array.

Comment: By the way, i recommend reading about [Normalizing State Shape](https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html) from the `redux` documentations. there are great examples of shaping the state